# How can I remove the border of a WPF window when using luna or classic?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

When I display a WPF window with `WindowStyle="None"`, it looks great when using areo.

However, when I use luna or classic, it displays an ugly gray border about 5 pixels wide.

Of course, if I set `ResizeMode="NoResize"`, this border disappears, but I would like the window to be resizable (`ResizeMode="CanResize"`).

Other non WPF applications (live mail, ie, firefox, etc.) do not display this gray border, but are still resizable.

Is there a way to remove this border while still being resizable?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm using the WPF Customizable Window's Essential Window. Here's my window declaration (abbreviated):

```
    <CustomWindow:EssentialWindow 
      xmlns:aero="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
      xmlns:CustomWindow="clr-namespace:CustomWindow;assembly=CustomWindow"
      AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" 
      ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
      WindowStyle="None"
      ShowInTaskbar="True" >
```

Comment: That looks like a cool project. I'd never heard of it before.

Comment: The project is cool, but have some problems like the windows covering the taskbar when maximized. UseMicrosoft WPF Shell Integration Library instead http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell

Comment: Using a 3rd party library is never a solution.

Answer (score 14):

Try setting [AllowsTransparency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.allowstransparency.aspx) to True on the Window.

Comment: This for the tip. That's not the answer though as AllowTransparency=true disables resizing.

Comment: Yes, you lose resizing from the window edges, but you can still resize with the grip.  You can handle resizing from the wnidow edges yourself, if you are interested I can post the code.

Comment: @JohnMyczek could you post the code of resizing window when AllowsTransparency is set to True?

Answer (score 12):

I found a better answer. No need to mess around with ResizeMode. No need for interop calls. No need to set AllowsTransparency which can have side effects.

```
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
 <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="0" ResizeBorderThickness="5" />
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
```

I took this answer from this thread: [How to create a WPF Window without a border that can be resized via a grip only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611298/how-to-create-a-wpf-window-without-a-border-that-can-be-resized-via-a-grip-only)

I repost it here for people who land here searching google.

Comment: Best answer! With winformshost support