# How to avoid sizing grip overlap in Window

Tags: wpf, xaml

I made a WPF `Window` containing `StatusBar` with `StatusBarItem` and `ProgressBar`.

The Window has a property `ResizeMode` set to `CanResizeWithGrip`.

It shows the sizing grip properly, but it overlaps elements underneath:

[image]

How can I avoid this overlap? I can set right margin to the progress bar, but how large? I don't want to use any magic numbers or hardcoded values. It would be also nice to have this resolved purely in XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change style for "Window" considering all wishes.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969824(v=vs.110).aspx
or https://stackoverflow.com/a/8278917/3492412

Or can do something like this

```
<StatusBar VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <StatusBarItem x:Name="statusbar" Background="Gray"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <DockPanel>
                <ResizeGrip DockPanel.Dock="Right" Visibility="Hidden" />
                <ProgressBar Background="red" Height="20"  Value="50" />
            </DockPanel>
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
```