# How to remove blue resize window border on WIndows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, window, border, windows-10

For my surprise, when I run my WPF application in Windows 10, I get a blue border around my windows. I believe that's something to do with resizing with the grip, as of the area I would have to place the mouse, because some of the windows, like pop-ups, are normal and cannot be resized.

I've checked other Q&A, and apparently they make use of WindowChrome to reach it. I would like to keep .NET 4.0 as the minimum pre-requisite for my application, if possible, so I couldn't use this approach. I would also like to maintain the resizability of my window.

Is there any **simple** way of hiding the border?

Btw, no luck with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611298/how-to-create-a-wpf-window-without-a-border-that-can-be-resized-via-a-grip-only) response, the border is still there.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you looking for is

select the mainWindow and from properties > Appearance

change the BorderThickness or WindowStyle

Answer (score -2):

First pressed Cap Lock, its light comes on. Then press Esc. The blue outline is gone!