# Remove windows padding Modern UI

Tags: c#, wpf, modern-ui

How can i **make the black and the blue component hit** **the application borders**? I don't want to have those white spaces at the edge. I tried by setting the padding to 0 in the Main windows and in both childs views and nothing happended.
[image]

I searched but i could not find any resource that point me to the right direction.

**UPDATE**

The main windows XAML. The Pages/Home.xaml load 2 childs view with no content. Just background color.

```
<mui:ModernWindow x:Class="ModernUINavigationApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
        Title="modernui" IsTitleVisible="True" Padding="0,0,0,0" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
        LogoData="F1 M 24.9015,43.0378L 25.0963,43.4298C 26.1685,49.5853 31.5377,54.2651 38,54.2651C 44.4623,54.2651 49.8315,49.5854 50.9037,43.4299L 51.0985,43.0379C 51.0985,40.7643 52.6921,39.2955 54.9656,39.2955C 56.9428,39.2955 58.1863,41.1792 58.5833,43.0379C 57.6384,52.7654 47.9756,61.75 38,61.75C 28.0244,61.75 18.3616,52.7654 17.4167,43.0378C 17.8137,41.1792 19.0572,39.2954 21.0344,39.2954C 23.3079,39.2954 24.9015,40.7643 24.9015,43.0378 Z M 26.7727,20.5833C 29.8731,20.5833 32.3864,23.0966 32.3864,26.197C 32.3864,29.2973 29.8731,31.8106 26.7727,31.8106C 23.6724,31.8106 21.1591,29.2973 21.1591,26.197C 21.1591,23.0966 23.6724,20.5833 26.7727,20.5833 Z M 49.2273,20.5833C 52.3276,20.5833 54.8409,23.0966 54.8409,26.197C 54.8409,29.2973 52.3276,31.8106 49.2273,31.8106C 46.127,31.8106 43.6136,29.2973 43.6136,26.197C 43.6136,23.0966 46.127,20.5833 49.2273,20.5833 Z"          
        ContentSource="/Pages/Home.xaml">


    <!--<mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>
        <mui:LinkGroup DisplayName="welcome">
            <mui:LinkGroup.Links>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="home" Source="/Pages/Home.xaml" />
                <mui:Link DisplayName="mypage" Source="/Pages/BasicPage.xaml" />
            </mui:LinkGroup.Links>
        </mui:LinkGroup>
        <mui:LinkGroup DisplayName="settings" GroupKey="settings">
            <mui:LinkGroup.Links>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="software" Source="/Pages/SettingsPage.xaml" />
            </mui:LinkGroup.Links>
        </mui:LinkGroup>
    </mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>

    <mui:ModernWindow.TitleLinks>
        <mui:Link DisplayName="settings" Source="/Pages/SettingsPage.xaml" />
        <mui:Link DisplayName="help" Source="https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui" />
    </mui:ModernWindow.TitleLinks>-->
</mui:ModernWindow>
```

Comment: Can we see your XAML?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611298/how-to-create-a-wpf-window-without-a-border-that-can-be-resized-via-a-grip-only - might help

Comment: @Carl done. Please check